# What does ?=^ mean in a regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write regexp which allows some special characters like `#-.` and it should contain at least one letter. I want to understand below things also:

```
/(?=^[A-Z0-9. '-]{1,45}$)/i
```

In this regexp what is the meaning of `?=^` ? What is a subexpression in regexp?

Comment: What you want to look for is the lookahead `(?=`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 8):

`(?=)` is a lookahead, it's looking ahead in the string to see if it matches without actually capturing it

`^` means it matches at the BEGINNING of the input (for example with the string `a test`, `^test` would not match as it doesn't start with "test" even though it contains it)

Overall, your expression is saying it has to `^` start and `$` end with 1-45 `{1,45}` items that exist in your character group `[A-Z0-9. '-]` (case insensitive `/i`). The fact it is within a lookahead in this case just means it's not going to capture anything (zero-length match).

Answer (score 6):

`?=` is a positive lookahead

[Read more on regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick, but it's only going to be a lookahead when used in conjunction with parentheses: `(?=)`.

Comment: @MariusSchulz yes, you are right. This is relative to the question being asked regarding *the meaning of "?=^"* - I should have also addressed the `^`, but having the OP read more from documentation wouldn't hurt